# Count the number of child records on the each parent record

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm stuck here and not sure why this code is not working. I want to throw error if the child record (Contact)is more than 5 records per Parent record (Account)

Question: I want to restrict the user to create a child record for every parent record.
say each parent record can have upto 5 child records.

Parent: Account
Child: Contact

I have created a custom field in the Account object to track the number of counts of Contact.

Here is my code:

```
trigger triggerContact on Contact (before insert, before update, after insert, after update, after delete) { 

    Integer maxChildRecord = 5;
         
    List<Contact> contacts = Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new;
     
    Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>(); 
    
    for (Contact c : contacts) { 
        if (c.AccountId != null) {
            acctIds.add(c.AccountId); 
        }
    } 
    
    Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>(); 

    for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT AccountId AcctId, Count(id) ContactCount 
                               FROM Contact 
                               WHERE AccountId in: acctIds 
                               GROUP BY AccountId]){
       
        accountMap.put((Id)ar.get('AcctId'), new Account(Id = (Id)ar.get('AcctId'), Contact_Count__c = (Integer)ar.get('ContactCount')));
        
    }
     
     List<Account> acctsToRollup = new List<Account>();
    for(Account account : accountMap.values()) {  
        Integer dbChildCount = (Integer)account.Contact_Count__c;
         
        
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Id =  account.Id;  
        a.Contact_Count__c = (Integer)account.Contact_Count__c;   
         
        if (dbChildCount > maxChildRecord){ 
            account.addError('can not add more child!');
        }else { 
            acctsToRollup.add(a);
        } 
    }

    if (acctsToRollup.size() > 0) {
        update acctsToRollup;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of logical issues

1. The `addError` needs to be on the object's trigger context. In this scenario add the Error on the Account Trigger and not on the contact. In your Contact trigger context, addError won't throw an error unless you add an error on the triggered contact record. I would simply move the addError part of the logic to a before update trigger on the Account.

   ```
   trigger triggerContact on Account ( before update) { 

    Integer maxChildRecord = 5;


    for(Account acc: trigger.new) {
       if(dbChildCount > maxChildRecord) {
        acc.addError('can not add more child!'');
      }
    }

   }
   ```

The above logic could also be a **simple validation rule**.

2. Make sure your trigger context is after Insert, after update and after delete, and your trigger code logic for contact count should not run on before triggers.

Few code pointers, do not have logic inside Trigger and try to move your logic to a Helper class or adopt a [Trigger Framework](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/success-cloud-coding-conventions/implement-frameworks-sc) for better maintainability.

**Update**

Now since your preference is to keep all the logic on Contact itself here is how I would modify the code,

```
trigger triggerContact on Contact (before insert, before update, after insert, after update, after delete) { 

Integer maxChildRecord = 5;
     
List<Contact> contacts = Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new;
 
Map<Id, List<Contact>> mapAcctIdContactList = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();

for(Contact c : contacts) {
    if(String.isNotBlank(c.AccountId)){
        if(!mapAcctIdContactList.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
            mapAcctIdContactList.put(c.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
        }
        mapAcctIdContactList.get(c.AccountId).add(c);
    }
}

Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>(); 

for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT AccountId AcctId, Count(id) ContactCount 
                           FROM Contact 
                           WHERE AccountId in: mapAcctIdContactList.keyset() 
                           GROUP BY AccountId]){
   
    accountMap.put((Id)ar.get('AcctId'), new Account(Id = (Id)ar.get('AcctId'), Contact_Count__c = (Integer)ar.get('ContactCount')));
    
}
 
 List<Account> acctsToRollup = new List<Account>();
 for(Account account : accountMap.values()) {  
    Integer dbChildCount = (Integer)account.Contact_Count__c;
     
    Account a = new Account();
    a.Id =  account.Id;  
    a.Contact_Count__c = (Integer)account.Contact_Count__c;   
     
    if (dbChildCount > maxChildRecord){
        for(Contact c: mapAcctIdContactList.get(account.Id) {
            c.addError('can not add more child!');
        }
    }else { 
        acctsToRollup.add(a);
    } 
}

if (acctsToRollup.size() > 0) {
    update acctsToRollup;
 }
```

Carefully note how I am storing all contacts for the Account that came in through (trigger.new/trigger.old) using the data structure  `Map<Id, List<Contact>>`

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm trying to do, I'm restricting the user to create certain records (in contact) for a given parent record (account) but why do you say that I can use simple validation rule? how I'm going to get the count of every child records of an parent record?, PS for the sake of simplicity I use the code inside trigger but usually I don't have any logic inside the trigger.

Comment: What I meant was you will still write the logic to count number of records in contact trigger as you have but the count check needs to be on Account. You cannot have a trigger on Contact and do an addError on Account.

Comment: is that possible to use addError in the Contact trigger? because I'm creating a contact record so I want the error to popup while creating the Contact record

Comment: Even with addError on Account the error will be displayed on Contact record. Other way is you will need to find all the trigger.new contact records under the Account and do an addError there. Hope that helps

Comment: So in my above code I’m doing adderror on account then why it’s not showing the error message

Comment: Because account is not in the context of this trigger as the triggered event is on Contact. While if you had the addError on the Account that would make both contact and Account as a trigger context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136793/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-nick-kahn).